# copy, resize, move image with php

Tags: php, image, image-scaling, image-resizing

I'm looking to copy, resize, and move an image. This is simular to how wordpress creates different sizes of the images when you upload. I want this to be executable without uploading anything just running when you run the page.

example:

```
$imagePath = 'http://example.com/images/myimageonserver.jpg';
$newImagePath = 'http://example.com/images/new/myimageonserver.jpg';
$newImageWidth = 300;
$newImageHeight = 200;
```

Does anyone know a script that will do this? Or some useful functions that can get this done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote [this Class](https://github.com/rockerest/nox/blob/master/classes/backbone/Image.php) a while ago to wrap the GD library functions.

You can call it like:

```
$image = new Image('original/path/to.file', 'destination/of/resized.file');
$image->resize(300, 200);
$image->output();
$image->clean();
```

### update:

This class no longer functions as explained above.
Here is a new example:

```
$image = new Image();
$image->source('original/path/to.file');
$image->destination('destination/of/resized.file');
$image->Manipulate->Resize(300,200);
$image->output();
$image->clean();
```

Comment: @spankmaster79 Really?  18 months later?  You're a good internet citizen, SpankMaster.  Here: I'll even update the links for you.

Comment: Doesn’t work. I keep getting `Fatal error: Class 'backbone\ImageBase' not found in ...`

Comment: @JonKantner if you want to use it verbatim, you'll need to include an autoloader like the one [here](https://github.com/rockerest/nox/blob/master/components/system/Preload.php#L19), which allows php to autoload the `backbone` directory out of `classes`. However, I recommend that you incorporate this class into your own project with more localized integrations instead of simply copy/pasting it in as is. By the way, this answer is almost 5 years old, and the library is homerolled. I'm almost positive you can find alternatives using [packagist](https://packagist.org/search/?q=image)/composer

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried the [GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)? Very powerful.

Comment: Yeah I've used ImageMagick in the past but started using GD and I like it a lot more

Answer (score 1):

Use the [GD Lib](http://php.net/manual/de/book.image.php) or [ImageMagick](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/book.imagick.php).
With ImageMagick it is the [resizeImage](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.imagick-resizeimage.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not to sure if this is what you're trying to accomplish, but see if this helps:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use ImageWorkshop class which based on the GD library: http://phpimageworkshop.com/ (on github: https://github.com/Sybio/ImageWorkshop)